# Div positioning inside another div (that repeats) inside a main container div

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

My requirement is

1. I want my teams to get listed, with the team owner. I have a list component, which contains many card component.
2. Each card contains Team owner image(at the left end), followed by team owner name, and an arrow at right end of the card
3. If the user wants to view the detail, then he can click an arrow that appears at the right end of each card.

My template.html content is as below

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="/img/csk.jpg"></img>
            <h5><strong>Raghav</strong></h5>
            <div class="section">
                <i class="icon assertive ion-heart">18</i>
                <i class="icon ion-chatbubbles positive-900">2</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="/img/dd.jpeg"></img>
            <h5><strong>Subramaniyan</strong></h5>
            <div class="section">
                <i class="icon assertive ion-heart">5</i>
                <i class="icon ion-chatbubbles positive-900">10</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Stylesheet is as below

```
.list {
    position: absolute;
    background-color : #607;
    top: 0 px;
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 100 % ;
}
.card {
    background - color: #BFF;
    position: relative;
    top: 2 % ;
    padding - left: 10 % ;
    padding - bottom: 15 % ;
    padding - right: 80 % ;
    margin: 5 % ;
    border - radius: 2 % ;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card:hover, .card.hover {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      padding-bottom: 50.25%;
}

.avatar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20 % ;
    background - color: #0E0;
}

.avatar > h5{
  position : relative; 
  width:100%; 
  left : 25%;
  top : 0%;
  padding-top:5%;   
}

.avatar img{
  position : absolute;
  left : 5%;
  top : 25%;
  float : left;
  border-radius:50%;
  width :15%;
  height :auto;
  max-height : 50%;     
}
.avatar .section{
  position : relative; 
  top : 30%;
  left :50%;
  width :150px;
  height : auto;    
}
.avatar > .section > *{
  left : 30%;
  width : 50%; 
  padding-right:5px;   
}

.avatar .arrow{
  position : relative;  
  border-radius:50%;
  width : 20%;
  height : 20%;
  float : right;
}
```

Error :

I am not able to see the `<div class="avatar">` in the page, when I run

[image]

Comment: looks like it is shown here http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/mhm3ncsu/

Comment: No.. the background-color is not shown. Offcourse, I am not using the full area of avatar.. so atleast some portion of that color needs to be visible

Comment: What is the `</img>` for? What does that do?

Comment: Should i remove it? I know close tag for img is not required. But is it an error?

Comment: @sabari Yes, an end tag for `img` is forbidden. I don't think it may be the cause of problems here, but  it's best to not take your chances. Did this say something else before? Was it an `svg` or something?